# How to find dependency conflict in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management

I'm trying to add nineoldandroid lib to my project, but I can't find where my dependency problem occurs. 
My dependencies:

```
dependencies {
   compile files('src/main/libs/guice-3.0-no_aop.jar')
   compile files('src/main/libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
   compile files('src/main/libs/roboguice-2.0.jar')
   compile files('src/main/libs/junit-4.11.jar')
   compile files('src/main/libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar')
   compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:20.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
   compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
   compile 'io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:2.0.7'
   compile ('com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'){
      exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
      exclude module: 'support-v4'
      exclude module: 'support-annotations'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.*'
      exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
      exclude group: 'com.android.dx'
   }
   //compile project(':android-spinwheel')
}
```

Error I get:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    /home/usr/soft/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/21.0.1/dx --dex --num-threads=4 --output /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/dex/debug /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/classes/debug /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/dependency-cache/debug /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/internal_impl-21.0.0-d8c58b966f1337ac583be7169abe38eafaaea523.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/hamcrest-core-1.3-42a42e6ec38e3a6ec6a99347d11a9296a04eca00.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-3528df59bfffc0f1961007c5282087aa82de987f.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/guice-3.0-no_aop-91a65442530b2d5fb3bf96359d70d249985649f6.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/otto-1.3.5-c4d763fed0f5fe8a97ac31f49ba37d2cd1567ad8.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-8250441981c0a4195e9e6068c3efdb149c0dedfd.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-f112c8b8d83a64a7f22e07537d04c10f33f5ab35.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/jsr305-1.3.9-4b2d061766ae6ca309e240b50953cd2ffef968a0.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/roboguice-2.0-6654a0e822af0f9305ce06f00f0d4e61dfab50fd.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/classes-ae9e0725b0368edcf3df124ccecd0b5e1ad65358.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/javax.inject-1-f4b5053b6356ac4792c8e5f52c58c62ca27a07cb.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/junit-4.11-2882cc48337848b98707492071ee6cb29be1a828.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/library-2.4.0-75e51598c065016181fac0cecd368e796b5769a8.jar /home/usr/vc/android-local/app/build/intermediates/pre-dexed/debug/support-annotations-21.0.0-ecd4ef2c68ca29b6a76021f4c9ef5fc3656e79db.jar
Error Code:
2
Output:
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define    Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:302)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:214)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

As you can see I have tried every exclude I can think of, I hope I'm using it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SpinnerWheel library you are using has an outdated version of nineoldandroids added as a jar. You will need to remove it and add the updated gradle dependency or update the jar to the version you specified in your primary gradle file.

In the most recent (as of this writing) I was doing the same thing, running into the same problem. It took a while to find because Android Studio was hiding the libs directory so I had to navigate to that folder to remove the jar.

If you are no longer using the SpinnerWheel library it will be the the same thing happening in one of your other dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I am having a similar problem with yours but with `Otto` library. My problem is that I have a jar in my libs folder and I have added another version(branch) of the same library from `maven repository`. If I remove one of them this problem is solved but I need both of them. That's because I want to use `AndroidAnnotations`

But I cant figure out how I can do that.

> Returning to your problem from what I can see you can solve it like this:

You have to find which one of the libraries that you have added has a dependency conflict with `nineoldandroids` library. You have to remove them one by one and find which one of them is. After you find that try to solve the conflict between these 2 libraries.

I hope this helps you.